# How can I count the length of the output of print in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to count the length of an output from print in Python?
For example, I want to count the length of the output:

```
print ("|L|",*L, sep='')
```

where *L* is a list.

I am not trying to get the `len(L)`, rather I want to know the length of the output of the print statement above after printing.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: im not familiar with all stackexchange domains and their purpose, this one says (programmers) and that's what my question is regarding!

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) referred in prior comment?

Comment: yes, i already added it for the future,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the text first in a string:

```
elements = ['|L |'] + L
text = ''.join(elements)
```

or if the list contains something other than strings:

```
elements = ['|L |'] + L
text = ''.join(map(str, elements))
```

then check the length:

```
length = len(text)
```

and finally output the text:

```
print(text)
```

Note that you will get the length of the string, not the actual number of characters printed on the screen. For example, ANSI escape sequences which change the color of the console will be included in the length of the string, while they aren't displayed in the console itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, though what is (s) in this case?